# Unwanted border around the image

Tags: graphics

I have taken a screenshot of a figure, cropped it and then inserted it into my document. Now, in the generated pdf file, an unwanted border is visible around the image as shown below.

**My code:**

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
  \includegraphics[width = 6in, height = 8cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/relatedMatter/TreeGNG.png}
    \caption{gestaucht}
    \label{Image:TreeGNG}
\end{figure}
```

**Image with unwanted border:**

[image]

**Original cropped image:**

[image]

Comment: Is it also visible if you zoom in to the border or print it out? maybe the rendering of the pdf viewer is not that good....

Comment: @Faekynn: Seems like you got the point. They not the actual borders. sometimes they appear only on the top and the left side. Their appearance depends upon the zoom level and cursor position.

Comment: If possible, try another pdf viewer. I'm quite happy with mupdf on linux and SumatraPDF on Win.
I encountered many rendering imperfections with the Adobe and Foxit reader...

Comment: @Faekynn: I will try but I use Mac OS. Any particular suggestion for that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you with Mac OS. But I've found a possibilty to install MuPDF: http://brewformulas.org/Mupdf
But I don't know, what this homebrew is...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVR7p.png) is *not* properly cropped. The margins are still present, they are only made transparent.

## Bitmap images

If the original image is a bitmap image, then use a better image editor (`gimp`, ...) to really remove the margins from the image.
Example with the `netpbm` tools:

```
pngtopnm -background white -mix <ruJ761V.png | pnmcrop | pnmtopng >TreeGNG-cropped.png
```

The options `-background white -mix` set the transparent pixels to white in this image. Then they are removed with the remaining margin of the image by `pnmcrop`.

> [image: Cropped result]

In case of a different page color, the white background of the image can be made transparent, e.g. using `gimp` with its function "Menu → Colors → Color to Alpha":

> [image: Cropped result with transparent background]

## Vector images

If the original image is a vector based format (PDF, EPS), then the conversion to a bitmap image would loose quality. Then tools like `pdfcrop` are better. Also options `viewport` or `trim` with `clip` can be used to crop the image at TeX level in `\includegraphics`.

In this case the original PDF file can be found [here](http://uhra.herts.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/2299/3968/901763.pdf). The image is on page 3 in Figure 3.

There are lots of ways for the `viewport` values. They specify the coordinates for the lower left and upper right corner:

```
viewport=<llx> <lly> <urx> <ury>
```

The default unit is bp, when no unit is given. TeX units can also be given explicitly. The origin is the lower left corner.

There are lots of ways to get these values:

- Printing in natural size and measuring with a ruler.
- Measuring in programs, for example, `gv` shows the cursor position with coordinates in unit bp.
- Overlaying the image with a grid (TikZ, package `pagegrid`, ...).

A separate document helps to experiment. The `\fbox` shows the new bounding box of the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
\fbox{%
  \includegraphics[
    page=3,
    viewport=80.5 524 299 684,
    clip,
  ]{901763.pdf}%
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Alternative with `pdfpages`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[
  fitpaper,
  pages=3,
  viewport=80.5 524 299 684,
]{901763.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The values can be refined manually or, when the other elements on the page are removed, the test document without `\fbox` can then be run through `pdfcrop`.

Then the result can be used directly or the values for `viewport` can be adjusted.

Refined values, e.g.:

```
viewport=80.65 524.4 298.55 683.7
```

In the document the options are used:

```
\includegraphics[page=3, viewport=80.65 524.4 298.55 683.7, clip]{901763.pdf}
```

### Measuring with grid in TikZ

If no program can be found, which shows the positions nicely, then
a grid could be put over the image:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand\ImageName{901763.pdf}
\newcommand\ImagePage{3}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
    x=1bp, y=1bp, % units
  ]
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above right] (image)
      {\includegraphics[page=\ImagePage]{\ImageName}};
    \draw[ultra thin, cyan] (0, 0) grid[step=10] (image.north east);
    \draw[very thin, red] (0, 0) grid[step=100] (image.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Origin is the lower left corner. The cyan lines are 10 bp apart, then red lines 100 bp:

> [image: Result grid]

Counting the lines, a rough bounding box can be:

```
left:    80 bp
bottom: 520 bp
right:  300 bp
top:    690 bp
```

This values can be used to clip the image and increase the resolution of the lines to 1 bp and 10 bp:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand\ImageName{901763.pdf}
\newcommand\ImagePage{3}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,  
    x=1bp, y=1bp, % units
  ]
    \node[inner sep=0pt, above right] (image)
      {\includegraphics[page=\ImagePage]{\ImageName}};
    \draw[line width=.05pt, cyan] (0, 0) grid[step=1] (image.north east);
    \draw[ultra thin, blue] (0, 0) grid[step=10] (image.north east);
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \useasboundingbox (80, 520) (300, 690);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result finer grid]

Now, the origin at the left lower order is at (80 bp, 520 bp) and the cyan lines are 1 bp apart, the blue lines 10 bp.

Then the new bounding box (lines outside the wanted area) is:

```
left:    81 bp
bottom: 524 bp 
right:  299 bp
top:    684 bp
```

Rechecking the values find that the left component is a little too large,
thus the final bounding box could be:

```
viewport=80 524 299 684
```

Comment: I actually took a screenshot of a pdf file. The screenshot was in .png format. After that, I cropped that png image to get the required image. These borders are not the actual borders, they keep changing their place depending upon your cursor's position.

Comment: @skm Then you should use the PDF page for best quality; `pdflatex` can include PDF pages, specify the page with option `page` in `\includegraphics` and use `viewport` (or `trim`) with `clip` to select the correct area. If you are using `dvips`, then the PDF page can be converted to EPS, e.g. via `pdftops -f <(first) page> -l <(last) page> -eps <PDF file> <EPS file>`.

Comment: Sorry, I am not that much familiar with all this stuff. Could you please write a short code for it if possible.

Comment: Check the `graphicx` manual; it will explain these options.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Thanks a lot...super method. Image can come in a very clean way. The only doubt which I have in mind is...how did you decide the parameter for `vieport`. I mean, how do you know come to know that the parameters should be `80.65 524.4 298.55 683.7 ` ? Because, with that parameter, I am getting exactly what I needed.

Comment: @skm First I loaded the PDF file in `gv` and took the coordinates that `gv` reported from the cursor positions. Then I refined it manually, see the answer for more details.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: I am again trying to import an image from a pdf file using viewport. I tried to find the pixel locations in GIMP but then it is importing the wrong section of the pdf file.

Comment: @skm You can also use gimp, but pixels are *not* points (pt or bp). You have to take the resolution into account. If you cannot find the resolution, then use a `\includegraphics{...}` without optional options and measure the width and height. Then the resolution can be calculated using them with the pixel width and pixel height.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: I am still struggling with all this. In your reply, I understood that you mean to use `\includegraphics{...}` without any optional parameters. But i did not understand how can I use it to calculate resolution. Can you provide a working example?

Comment: @skm Pixel width=234 pixels, image width=5.6cm, *x* position from the left=78 pixels. Then *x* is (78 pixels/234 pixels)*5.6cm = 1.86667cm

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Sorry, Can't understand anything.

Comment: @skm If math is not an option, see the updated answer, which shows a way using a grid in TikZ.