# \paperwidth figure going out of margins

Tags: floats

I want my figure to be slightly bigger than \textwidth but when I use \paperwidth it goes out of the right margin. I want something like the first row, but in a figure environment so I can use the caption, how can I do it?

[image]

**EDIT**: added document class

**EDIT 2**: pages have different inner and outer margins, depending if they're even or odd

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{ociamthesis}
% margins in the class document
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.33in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.08in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.0in}

% desired output
\makebox[\textwidth]{\centering
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{img/avg_training_metrics}
\caption{Training accuracy and loss progress.}
\label{fig:training_avg}}
% current output
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/avg_training_metrics}
\caption{Training accuracy and loss progress.}
\label{fig:training_avg}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: What class and class options are you using?

Comment: from provided image i suspect that it have white space on left and right side. to test this, try `\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img/avg_training_metrics}}`

Comment: Yes, there are white spaces on both sides of the image, I also added the class details in the main post.

Comment: The pages have different inner and outer margins, so you have to distinguish whether you're on an even or odd page. Just centering is not enough.

Comment: @egreg I'm on an even page, how do I specify it?

Comment: seems to me that the different left and right margins shouldn't matter, since ordinarily a float will be set against the left margin.  so if you can shift the graphics "box" left by half the difference between `\pagewidth` and `\textwidth` (\hspace*{-<wd>} ) that should do the trick.  as long as the caption isn't inside that box, it should be positioned correctly.  (unable to test, hence a comment rather than an answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's obvious that your image has whitespace around it: The second image is set to be as wide as `\textwidth`, yet it doesn't fill out to the (red) margins:

[image]

The (green) whitespace is amplified when stretching the image to `\paperwidth` in the top image. To see the true whitespace around the images, you can use `\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image}}` (possibly with `\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}` to remove any additional space inserted by the `\fbox`).

I assume you're using even margins, although I may be wrong; this may influence the visual alignment.

My suggestion would be to do one of the following

1. Remove the whitespace around your images (either from the source, or through cropping using [`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `viewport` and `clip` key-values). A similar problem or removing an embedded border is discussed in [Unwanted border around the image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252040/5764).
2. Insert the image as-is in a box of pre-specified width (to avoid `\hbox` overfull warnings) and tweak the image width to somewhere between `\textwidth` and `\paperwidth`:

   ```
   \makebox[\textwidth]{%
     \includegraphics[width = 1.2\textwidth]{image}%
   }
   ```

   You can adjust the factor of `\textwidth` until the margins are within text text block boundary.

Comment: The only problem I have using \makebox is that the caption is not displayed

Comment: @AlessandroGaballo: `\makebox` would not affect the display of the `\caption` since that should be outside of the `\makebox`. Are you referring to the axis labels? Even they should not be affected since they're part of the image.

Comment: I'm referring to the figure's caption, I get the error \caption outside float

Comment: @AlessandroGaballo: You should put the `\caption` outside the `\makebox` but still inside the `figure` environment.