# How to remove the thin border around image (png, made from "save as picture" in powerpoint) in LATEX?

Tags: graphics, border

I insert a few subfigures into powerpoint and group them together, then I apply "save as picture" to save the composite figure as a png image. But when I include this png image into latex and view the PDF file, there are thin borders around each subfigure like below:
[image]

The latex code is

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{figure*}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{fig.png}
\caption{...}
\label{...}
\end{figure*}
```

I try various methods to remove the border:

(1) "set transparent color" in powerpoint (only works for some figures)
(2) export in Paint and save as to remove any transparency (not work)
(3) picture border for subfigure is no outline (not work)

I have many subfigures and each one has this problem. How can I solve that?

Any suggestion is welcome! Many thanks!!!

Comment: possible duplicate -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252040/unwanted-border-around-the-image?rq=1

Comment: @js bibra Thanks! I also saw this post and try the method but failed. This question is really puzzling.